# Active mq consumers count decreasing to 0

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic

We are facing a weird problem in which the activemq consumers for some random queues are decreasing till they become 0 after which they are not able to recover.
Once this happens we have to redeploy the consumer application again to start processing.
We have been struggling with this issue for some time but could not figure out the root cause.

activemq broker version 5.14.5

following is the connection configuration.

```
<bean id="activeMQIconnectConnectionFactory" class="test.ActiveMQIconnectConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)"/>
        <property name="prefetchPolicy" ref="prefetchPolicy"/>
        <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicy"/>
        <property name="trustAllPackages" value="true"/>
        <!-- http://activemq.apache.org/consumer-dispatch-async.html
        The default setting is dispatchAsync=true
         If you want better thoughput and the chances of having a slow consumer are low, you may want to change this to false.
         -->
        <property name="dispatchAsync" value="true"/>
        <!-- 
        whether or not timestamps on messages should be disabled or not. If you disable them it adds a small performance boost.
         Default is false
         -->
        <property name="disableTimeStampsByDefault" value="true"/>

        <!-- http://activemq.apache.org/optimized-acknowledgement.html
        This option is disabled by default but can be used to improve throughput in some circumstances as it decreases load on the broker.
         -->
        <property name="optimizeAcknowledge" value="true"/>
        <!-- Default 300ms
        For us, 5 sec.
         -->
        <property name="optimizeAcknowledgeTimeOut" value="5000"/>
        <property name="useAsyncSend" value="true"/>
        <property name="exceptionListener" ref="jmsExceptionListener"/>
    </bean>

 <bean id="testQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="test.queue"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsProducerFactoryPool" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" destroy-method="stop"
          init-method="start">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="activeMQIconnectConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="maxConnections" value="10"/>
        <property name="maximumActiveSessionPerConnection"
                  value="1000"/>
        <property name="createConnectionOnStartup" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsConsumerFactoryPool" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" destroy-method="stop"
          init-method="start">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="activeMQIconnectConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="maxConnections" value="10"/>
        <property name="maximumActiveSessionPerConnection"               value="1000"/>
        <property name="createConnectionOnStartup" value="true"/>
        <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true"/>
        <property name="idleTimeout" value="86400000"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="redeliveryPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
        <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="1"/>
        <property name="queue" value="*"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="prefetchPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy">
        <property name="queuePrefetch" value="500"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="com.minda.iconnect.jms.impl.TimedJmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsProducerFactoryPool"/>
        <property name="defaultDestinationName" value="iconnect.queue"/>
        <property name="deliveryPersistent" value="true"/>
        <!-- I think this is ingored if explicitQosEnabled is not set -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="simpleMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.jms.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter"/>

<bean id="testProducer"
          class="com.test.TestProducer">
        <property name="consumerDestination" ref="testQueu"/>
        <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate"/>
        <property name="messageConverter" ref="simpleMessageConverter"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="testContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConsumerFactoryPool"/>
        <property name="destination" ref="testS"/>
        <property name="messageListener">
            <bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter">
                <property name="delegate" ref="testConsumer"/>
                <property name="defaultListenerMethod" value="process"/>
                <property name="messageConverter" ref="simpleMessageConverter"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="50"/>
        <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="100"/>
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="false"/>
        <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

class for connectionFactory

```
public class ActiveMQIconnectConnectionFactory extends org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ActiveMQIconnectConnectionFactory.class);

    @Override
    public void setBrokerURL(String brokerURL)
    {
        // LOG when connecting to activemq
        // using this setter to be sure it's only logged once
        // See DJ-5780
        LOG.info("ActiveMQ configured is: " + (DEFAULT_BROKER_URL.equals(brokerURL) ? "(default init setting) " : "") + brokerURL);
        LOG.info("Connecting to ActiveMQ");
        super.setBrokerURL(brokerURL);
    }
}
```

Till now we have been playing around the parameters for timeouts etc but not luck.
We suspect that the issue is occurring due to some connection issue or handling of connections via DMLC, but could not identify the problem. Help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is a mix of Spring DMLC and AMQ behaviors based on your configurations affecting each other.

**try by changing :**

```
<property name="optimizeAcknowledgeTimeOut" value="500"/>
```

**AND**

org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.setReceiveTimeout(0);

**Or**

```
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.setReceiveTimeout(10000);
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.setIdleTaskExecutionLimit(100);
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.html#setReceiveTimeout-long-

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#setIdleTaskExecutionLimit-int-

> **public void setIdleTaskExecutionLimit(int
>   idleTaskExecutionLimit)** Specify the limit for idle executions of a
>   consumer task, not having received any message within its execution.
>   If this limit is reached, the task will shut down and leave receiving
>   to other executing tasks. The default is 1, closing idle resources
>   early once a task didn't receive a message. This applies to dynamic
>   scheduling only; see the "maxConcurrentConsumers" setting. The minimum
>   number of consumers (see "concurrentConsumers") will be kept around
>   until shutdown in any case.
>
> Within each task execution, a number of message reception attempts
>   (according to the "maxMessagesPerTask" setting) will each wait for an
>   incoming message (according to the "receiveTimeout" setting). If all
>   of those receive attempts in a given task return without a message,
>   the task is considered idle with respect to received messages. Such a
>   task may still be rescheduled; however, once it reached the specified
>   "idleTaskExecutionLimit", it will shut down (in case of dynamic
>   scaling).
>
> Raise this limit if you encounter too frequent scaling up and down.
>   With this limit being higher, an idle consumer will be kept around
>   longer, avoiding the restart of a consumer once a new load of messages
>   comes in. Alternatively, specify a higher "maxMessagesPerTask" and/or
>   "receiveTimeout" value, which will also lead to idle consumers being
>   kept around for a longer time (while also increasing the average
>   execution time of each scheduled task).

http://activemq.apache.org/performance-tuning.html

> **Optimized Acknowledge** When consuming messages in auto acknowledge mode
>   (set when creating the consumers' session), ActiveMQ can acknowledge
>   receipt of messages back to the broker in batches (to improve
>   performance). **The batch size is 65% of the prefetch limit for the
>   Consumer. Also if message consumption is slow the batch will be sent
>   every 300ms.** You switch batch acknowledgment on by setting
>   optimizeAcknowledge=true on the ActiveMQ ConnectionFactory.

http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html

> Once the broker has dispatched a prefetch limit number of messages to
>   a consumer **it will not dispatch any more messages to that consumer
>   until the consumer has acknowledged at least 50% of the prefetched
>   messages, e.g., prefetch/2, that it received.** When the broker has
>   received said acknowledgements it will dispatch a further prefetch/2
>   number of messages to the consumer to 'top-up', as it were, its
>   prefetch buffer. Note that it's possible to specify a prefetch limit
>   on a per consumer basis (see below).